# How to add a new column?

Tags: r, dataset

I know how to add columns but I don't understand what the directions are asking me so I'll post them below.

This is the data set that's called *Example.Data*

I need to add a new column with these rules to my existing data set

````
12 <= Educ < 16: “HighSchool”
16 <= Educ < 17: “College”
17 <= Educ < 19: “Masters”
Educ >= 19: “Doctorate”```


   Income   Career   Age   Sex  Married
1.   39540    Lawyer   20    F    N
2.   45098    Teacher  65    F    y
3.   54565    Doctor   45    M    y
4.   48356    Teacher  26    M    N
5.   68959    Nurse    32    F    y
6.   98459    Lawyer   34    F    Y
7.   34343    Nurse    49    M    N
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume there is a column of data named "Educ" you haven't **included** (just using first four rows):

| Income | Career | Age | Sex | Married | Educ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39540 | Lawyer | 20 | F | N | 18 |
| 45098 | Teacher | 65 | F | Y | 15 |
| 54565 | Doctor | 45 | M | Y | 22 |
| 48356 | Teacher | 26 | M | N | 16 |

Code:

```
Example.Data$Degree = ""

Example.Data[Example.Data$Edu>=12 & Example.Data$Edu<16,"Degree"] = "HighSchool"

Example.Data[Example.Data$Edu>=16 & Example.Data$Edu<17,"Degree"] = "College"

Example.Data[Example.Data$Edu>=17& Example.Data$Edu<19,"Degree"] = "Masters"    

Example.Data[Example.Data$Edu>=19,"Degree"] = "Doctorate"

View(Example.Data)
```

Resulting in:

| Income | Career | Age | Sex | Married | Educ | Degree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39540 | Lawyer | 20 | F | N | 18 | Masters |
| 45098 | Teacher | 65 | F | Y | 15 | HighSchool |
| 54565 | Doctor | 45 | M | Y | 22 | Doctorate |
| 48356 | Teacher | 26 | M | N | 16 | College |

There are more elegant ways of doing this but this is base R and is very clear what you are doing!

Comment: I appreciate the explanation but I'm still a little confused. Is there another step I need to do to see it with the original? When I entered that code nothing changed T.T

Comment: Yes, I assumed there was another column "Educ" and I just made up some data. The columns you posted are the only ones you were given? (edited my original answer to be "Educ" instead of "Edu")

Comment: You were right. There is a column called edu that I forgot to add.

Comment: great! if the code worked, would you mind accepting my answer? much appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry I think I confused us both. When I entered the code nothing happens. Was a table or chart supposed to appear?

Comment: I have updated the code to include what you might be what you are looking for

Comment: one last note: I assume you have a dataset loaded that is named "data"

Comment: I know see it was called Example.Data. Updating my answer now

Comment: okay updated, does that work for you?

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this one forever. Accepted! Just realized what I had to click. Thanks again and have a good night!

Answer (score 2):

you can use dplyr package and case_when function

```
df <- df %>% mutate(Degree = 
                case_when(
                  Educ >= 12 & Educ < 16 ~ "HighSchool",
                  Educ >= 16 & Educ < 17 ~ "College",
                  Educ >= 17 & Educ < 19 ~ "Masters",
                  Educ >= 19 ~ "Doctorate",
                  TRUE ~ NA_character_
                ))
```